# Automation testing react native app with appium

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, appium

I have two screen, Login screen and home screen, Login screen will loaded first.
So I want to test element button in Home Screen, but appium always render the first screen (Login Screen). It will return error, because appium can not read the element in home screen.

This is my Login Screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width: '50%', marginBottom: 10 }}
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          value={this.state.email}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          accessible={true}
          accessibilityLabel={'fieldEmail'}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          accessibilityLabel='buttonLogin'
          style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5 }}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my Home screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          accessibilityLabel='buttonHome'
          style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5 }}
          onPress={() => Alert.alert('Notification', 'Welcome home.')}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my test file

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import wd from 'wd'
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000
const PORT = 4723
const config = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  deviceName: 'Pixel 3a XL API 29',
  app: '/Users/gandahalojasa/Documents/Project/Learn/Appium_React_Native/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
}
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote('localhost', PORT)

beforeAll(async () => {
  await driver.init(config)
  await driver.sleep(4000)
}) // Sometime for the app to load

test('login screen test', async () => {
  expect(await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId('fieldEmail')).toBe(true)
  await driver.elementByAccessibilityId('fieldEmail').type('gandarainpanjaitan@gmail.com')
  expect(await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId('buttonLogin')).toBe(true)
  const element = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId('buttonLogin')
  await element.click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you validate ElementID using other tools to confirm? e.g. Android UIautomatorviewer to Appium Desktop Inspector?
Here's useful example for both.
http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-inspector/
http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector-inspect-mobile-elements/